# Python Flask SQLalchemy query filter by boolean values ignore False

Tags: python, python-2.7, filter, flask, sqlalchemy

In my database I have rooms, these rooms have multiple boolean values like `has_tv`.

A user can search for a room in a city, he will be redirected to the result page, where he finds all rooms in the searched city.

Now there is a filter function which filters the current result set, by rooms which for example have a tv. For this the user checks a checkbox with the value `has_tv`

I managed to make it work, but it does not ignore False values. this means if a user check `has_tv` it will be true but all the other boolean values will be false (because they are unchecked). So this will show me only results where has_tv is true and all others false, I need to see results where has_tv is true and others are irrelevant, some can be false and true.

Thats what I use atm:

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
    all_rooms_in_city = Zimmer.query.filter(or_(Zimmer.haustiere_erlaubt.is_(form.haustiere_erlaubt.data), Zimmer.bettwaesche_wird_gestellt.is_(form.bettwaesche_wird_gestellt.data))).all()
else:
    all_rooms_in_city = Zimmer.query.order_by(desc("stadt")).all()
```

That are all values which can be checked (there are a lot, so hardcoding all possibilites is impossible):

```
class FilterZimmerForm(Form):
    haustiere_erlaubt = BooleanField("Haustiere")
    bettwaesche_wird_gestellt = BooleanField("Bettwaesche")
    grill_vorhanden = BooleanField("grill_vorhanden")
    safe_vorhanden = BooleanField("safe_vorhanden")
    kuehlschrank_vorhanden = BooleanField("kuehlschrank_vorhanden")
    rauchen_erlaubt = BooleanField("rauchen_erlaubt")
    parkplatz_vorhanden = BooleanField("parkplatz_vorhanden")
    kochmoeglichkeit_vorhanden = BooleanField("kochmoeglichkeit_vorhanden")
    restaurant_im_haus_vorhanden = BooleanField("restaurant_im_haus_vorhanden")
    handtuecher_werden_gestellt = BooleanField("handtuecher_werden_gestellt")
    tv_vorhanden = BooleanField("tv_vorhanden")
    waschmoeglichkeit_vorhanden = BooleanField("waschmoeglichkeit_vorhanden")
    wlan_vorhanden = BooleanField("wlan_vorhanden")
```

Of course later if lets say two of them are checked, it shall show all rooms where the two checked values are true and all others shall not matter!

Here is a screenshot of the website where the function is needed:
[image]

**EDIT:**

It seems I found a solution, have tested a few times and it seems to work as intended but it does not feel like it is best practise:

```
if form.validate_on_submit():

    filter_result = []

    if form.haustiere_erlaubt.data == True:
        filter_result.append(Zimmer.haustiere_erlaubt.is_(True))
    if form.bettwaesche_wird_gestellt.data == True:
        filter_result.append(Zimmer.bettwaesche_wird_gestellt.is_(True))
    if form.grill_vorhanden.data == True:
        filter_result.append(Zimmer.grill_vorhanden.is_(True))
    if form.safe_vorhanden.data == True:
        filter_result.append(Zimmer.safe_vorhanden.is_(True))
    if form.kuehlschrank_vorhanden.data == True:
        filter_result.append(Zimmer.kuehlschrank_vorhanden.is_(True))
    if form.rauchen_erlaubt.data == True:
        filter_result.append(Zimmer.rauchen_erlaubt.is_(True))
    if form.parkplatz_vorhanden.data == True:
        filter_result.append(Zimmer.parkplatz_vorhanden.is_(True))
    if form.kochmoeglichkeit_vorhanden.data == True:
        filter_result.append(Zimmer.kochmoeglichkeit_vorhanden.is_(True))           
    if form.restaurant_im_haus_vorhanden.data == True:
        filter_result.append(Zimmer.restaurant_im_haus_vorhanden.is_(True))
    if form.handtuecher_werden_gestellt.data == True:
        filter_result.append(Zimmer.handtuecher_werden_gestellt.is_(True))
    if form.tv_vorhanden.data == True:
        filter_result.append(Zimmer.tv_vorhanden.is_(True))
    if form.waschmoeglichkeit_vorhanden.data == True:
        filter_result.append(Zimmer.waschmoeglichkeit_vorhanden.is_(True))
    if form.wlan_vorhanden.data == True:
        filter_result.append(Zimmer.wlan_vorhanden.is_(True))

    for item in filter_result:
        all_rooms_in_city = Zimmer.query.filter(item).all()
else:
    all_rooms_in_city = Zimmer.query.order_by(desc("stadt")).all()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First if you want to avoid hardcoding you need some way to get programatically which attributes you want to use to filter and what the appropriate field in the form is called. I guess you could scan the `Zimmer` class and get the name of all boolean attributes, but for now I simply asume a list of strings with the name of the attribute where in the form the name is the same:

```
filter_list = ["haustiere_erlaubt", ...]
```

Then you need to add the filters to the query *only if* the form is true. So:

```
if form.validate_on_submit():

    query = Zimmer.query

    for filter_name in filter_list:
        if getattr(form, filter_name).data:
            query = query.filter(getattr(Zimmer, filter_name).is_(True)))

    all_rooms_in_city = query.all()
```

I guess you could also build a dictionary of the appropriate filters and use `filter_by`:

```
filter_dict = { filter_name: True for filter_name in filter_list if getattr(form, filter_name).data }

all_rooms_in_city = Zimmer.query.filter_by(**filter_dict).all()
```

In your code you are redefining all_rooms_in_the_city in the for loop for each item, so only the last filter will actually apply.

Comment: thanks, I will try your code. That is actually exactly what I have done in my EDIT post, but yours looks way better.

Comment: In the code you posted is one important difference: For every "filterule" you do `all_rooms_in_city = Zimmer.query.filter(item).all()` which means that only one single filter will be "active". If you change it to something to `query = Zimmer.query; for item in filter_resuolt: query = query.filter(item)` you would use all filters.